# error while establishing connection with node.js server OpenShift

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

I am not managing to establish connection with the server is hosted in OpenShift.

the connection server is this:

```
var io = require ('socket.io') listen (8000);
```

client connection to is this one:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

the connection of OpenShift is this but not working:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://server-xatevo.rhcloud.com:8000');
```

the client is in my house and the server node.js this in OpenShift but can't establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on port 8080 on your server (but connect from your client on port 8000), you can see an example application here: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example/blob/master/server.js

The full repo is available here: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example

Comment: I have to deploy it on my server?

here is my apps: https://github.com/gfstark/server/blob/master/servidor.js

Comment: I installed it on OpenShift :https://github.com/jeremyosborne/chatty   but I do not know how to access the browser

Comment: Change "var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);" to "var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);"

Comment: @moleculartear Actually you should really use process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT instead of just hard coding 8080, like in the example you linked.

Comment: but if I switched and ran this example also work

chatty-xatevo.rhcloud.com

in gitub:

  https://github.com/jeremyosborne/chatty

I can not see the example do not know why!

Comment: You need to deploy the code to your OpenShift application using "git push"